# Show keyboard when touch on Edittext with external input device connected (Barcode Scanner)

Tags: input, keyboard, android-edittext, barcode

My Tablet is connected to an USB Barcode Scanner. This will automatically hide the keyboard as the system assume that you are using an external keyboard. Which is what i want. But I will need the softkey to showup when i touch on the Edittext inside my fragment. can anyone advise how i can do this?

Because i am very new to android programming, it would help alot if you can post a simple codes consist of a fragment and an Edittext . thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, found out to solve this, just need to do to settings -> Language and input.

Default -> turn off physical hardware keyboard